# ruby on rails: Convert an image file to byte array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, image, byte

I need to upload an image from a rails form using Ajax and convert it into a byte array to show a html preview of the image.

When I read the file, it returns me binary data which is not readable by img tag. I'm sure I'm doing something very silly and this might have an obvious solution. Here is the code snippet. Please help.

## rails

```
tmp = File.open(params[:file_upload][:my_file].tempfile, 'rb').read
render :text => tmp
```

## jquery

```
$("#item_detail_image").attr("src", "data:image/png;base64," + data.responseText);
```

I'm not using paperclip because I don't have a database connection to my rails application (I'm using web services) and I'm not sure how to use paperclip without ActiveRecord

Comment: Do you need to base64 encode the data? http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/base64/rdoc/Base64.html#method-i-encode64

Comment: Realising I should really have worded that in the form of an answer… here goes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to Base 64 encode the data.

See http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/base64/rdoc/Base64.html#method-i-encode64

Comment: Isn't that a bit bandwith-inefficient?

Comment: Could be, dependent on situation, but it's still the solution to the question. :p